# Disk full; Terminal in Recovery mode won’t delete files; boot kernel panics

Tags: terminal, bash, mojave

I’m in a pickle here. macOS Mojave, just updated the other day. I managed to fill my disk up while creating a .dmg, and the system froze. I rebooted. Kernel panic.

Boot to Recovery mode. Mount the disk. Open Terminal.

`–bash–3.2# rm /path/to/large/file
rm: /path/to/large/file: No space left on device`

Essentially the same issue as this Unix thread from ‘08!
https://www.unix.com/linux/69889-unable-remove-file-using-rm-disk-space-full.html

I’ve tried `echo x > /path/to/large/file`, no good.

It’s borked. Does anyone have any suggestions that aren’t “wipe the drive and restore from your backup”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spite this post is old, I decided to leave my solution here to help community with one more approach.

note: I wrote a [medium](https://medium.com/@eduardo.pinheiro.pt/your-mac-doesnt-restart-due-to-no-space-left-on-device-27adf777619d) with more description.

In my case, I din't have that extra partition available so, in recovery mode:

1. Run the terminal

   [image]
2. run `diskutil list`

[image]

3. Find the identifier of "VM" volume. In the case of the previous image is "disk1s5". You'll probably have "disk2s4"
4. delete the volume VM:

`diskutil apfs deleteVolume disk1s5`

(replace the disk1s5 for your VM identifier)

5. You are now able to remove files on "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Is it okay to delete Virtual Memory partition?

Comment: That's not a partition. It's a volume. If you're in rescue mode you will have no problems if you delete it. Just be careful to leave enouph available space in order for your OS to recreate it automatically. Enouph space is what you want for your OS to have available for virtual memory. You can think as a swap space in Linux (more or less).

Comment: Didn't work for me (macOS Catalina). Still "No space left on device". This is an iMac 2012 with a Fusion Drive.

Comment: Sometimes VM is 0, or very small, as in my case. Deleting it didn’t help.

Answer (score 4):

I am so lucky. Posting this to hopefully help others.

I had partitioned my APFS volume, and was able to delete the non-boot partition. This gave the boot volume enough space, and I'm back up. I'll clean up the drive and restore that volume.

I found a post on a ZFS forum that suggested that these new filesystems require *some* disk space to perform *any* disk operation. If you have 0% left, you're out of luck.

All other tricks to remove the file, to overwrite it with null data, failed.

`dd if=/dev/null of=/path/to/large/file` failed.

`true |> /path/to/large/file` (or something similar, I forget the exact command) failed.

Everything failed, except booting in to Recovery mode and, without mounting any drives first, deleting the extra APFS partition.

Lesson: keep a ~100MB dummy partition (or just quota your main drive so it can't take up 100% of the physical disk) as your get-out-of-jail card.

Edit: I actually mean that I had multiple APFS volumes on my boot partition, and that I deleted one of those volumes. Old language dies hard.

Answer (score 0):

On 10.14 (Mojave) I was able to recover from this situation by booting into recovery mode (hold Cmd+R on the chime) and then manually deleting a few large files.

Despite several (older) pages on the Internet saying this doesn't work, it did and I'm writing this answer from that system, everything booted well afterwards and I've not seen any signs of corruption or data loss.

This might work because I remember that Unix systems reserve a bit of space and inodes for the superuser. Or it might simply be that single-user mode bypasses whatever causes `rm` to not work when the drive is full.

Comment: It doesn’t work if you don’t have enough free space. In my case, I have 880 bytes free, and that’s not enough apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Using recovery mode to remove some large files to free up disk space also works in 10.13.6 (High Sierra).  The steps are:

- Reboot into recovery mode (restart and immediately hold Cmd+R)
- Open up a Terminal session from the top menu
- Navigate to a folder containing some large files (e.g. /System/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/ and remove them using rm -rf
- Reboot