# Can't delete files from APFS volume -- no space left on device

Tags: apfs

My Late 2012 iMac's APFS Fusion Drive is full (53 KB free) and caused the system to freeze. I've rebooted into Recovery Mode but I cannot remove any files: `rm XXX: no space left on device`. `fsck_apfs` reports no problems. I found [some suggestion somewhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338721/disk-full-terminal-in-recovery-mode-won-t-delete-files-boot-kernel-panics/338724#338724) to remove the APFS Volume named 'VM', but after removing this volume the error remains. After installing macOS on an external disk I tried removing the snapshots, but that resulted in an error. After restarting the snapshots are no longer listed.

The APFS container is the default setup per Catalina on a Fusion drive. There are 2 physical store disks and 5 volumes (Data, Preboot, Recovery, VM & System).

I don't want to reinstall macOS. How can I free up some space such that macOS can boot?

Comment: I’m going to put a hold on this. We would need to see the [disk layout and commands you are using to diagnose the fix properly.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358837/5472)

Answer (score 3):

APFS is a CoW (Copy on Write) filesystem therefore anything (includes deleting files) requires writable disk space to perform those actions ([refer to this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1513586/my-apple-apfs-partition-is-entirely-full-and-now-i-cant-delete-anything-anymor)).

In your case, if removing VM doesn't help (because VM is dynamically-sized, and may happen to have a size of 0 when you attempted to remove it, therefore gave you no extra space), try:

- Get Recovery volume's (where recoveryOS lives in) identifier with `diskutil list`.
- Then use `diskutil apfs deleteVolume IDENTIFIER`

This should give you some space to delete files. Clean up immediately.

**This will also ruin your recoveryOS, to restore recoveryOS installation, just:**

Download latest macOS update at https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos and install it. Supplemental updates and security updates are all good.

EDIT: If you're on **Big Sur** (latest at the time of posting), use Mac App Store to download a full image (I know it's big, but you have to) at: `itms-apps://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132` (this is the URL scheme for Mac App Store, paste it in any browser)

Comment: There are no macOS updates available to download for Big Sur from that link unfortunately. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @grg Consider downloading full image on App Store at (opens MAS directly): itms-apps://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132

Comment: I’m in this mess now. Deleting the recovery volume, requires you to be either still in your booted OS normally, or have booted off a USB stick right?